# Are AngularJS Services singletons really?

Tags: angularjs, singleton

If angular services are singletons, why objects created inside them could have more than a single instance? 
Hope you may clarify this thing.
Thanks in advance
Ariel

Comment: there is only 1 instance and there could be MANY references to this same instance.

Comment: You mean 1 service => 1 object => n references ?

Comment: 1 service has only instance (object) in memory and you could have many references to this instance.